# Is there any way to disable ModalBottomSheetLayout gestures? - Jetpack compose

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to implement **google map** inside the content of **modal bottom sheet layout.** The problem is when I try to drag on map, the modal bottom sheet is moving. I tried to find a solution for a google map to take an advantage of sheet's gestures, but with no luck.

I know that bottom sheet scaffold has option of disabling gestures, but then I can't use scrim color that is necessary in my project.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is really any way, all I could find was this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242384339?pli=1. But this is a hack as the answer to the issue points and your Google Map might not work properly inside.
Nonetheless it is a weird design decision to place a map inside a Sheet Layout

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the pointer events, apply the scrolling offset directly to the map, and then mark the event as consumed, so it does not reach the parent component.

Note: This does not handle pinch to zoom or rotate.

```
val targetPosition = LatLng(SOME_LAT, SOME_LNG)
val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
    position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(targetPosition, 17f)
}

GoogleMap(
    modifier =
        Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            .height(300.dp)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                awaitPointerEventScope {
                    while (true) {
                        awaitPointerEvent(pass = PointerEventPass.Main).changes.forEach {
                            val offset = it.positionChange()
                            cameraPositionState.move(
                                CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(-offset.x, -offset.y)
                            )
                            it.consume()
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GoogleMap(
        modifier = Modifier
            .matchParentSize()
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures { _, dragAmount ->
                    cameraPositionState.move(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(-dragAmount.x, -dragAmount.y))
                }
            },
    )
```

depending on levi answer [Is there any way to disable ModalBottomSheetLayout gestures? - Jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73950467/is-there-any-way-to-disable-modalbottomsheetlayout-gestures-jetpack-compose/74944848#74944848)
thanks it's work